# Parsing variable length input file into objects - suggestions?

Tags: text-parsing

I have been given the task of writing a small ATM program where. The program  upon receives an input file, runs through the file, carrying out instructions.

The input file is of the following format:

8000 
 
12345678 1234 1234 
500 100 
B 
W 100 
 
87654321 4321 4321 
100 0 
W 10

The first line is the total cash held in the ATM followed by a blank line. The remaining input represents zero or more user sessions. Each session consists of:
The user's account number, correct PIN and the PIN they actually entered. These are separated by spaces.
Then, on a new line, the customer's current balance and overdraft facility.
Then, one or more transactions, each on a separate line. These can be one of the following types: 
Balance inquiries, represented by the operation code B.
Cash withdrawals, represented by the operation code W followed by an amount.
A blank line marks the end of a user session.

I am able to write the part of the program that carries out the transactions and outputs results.

What I need help on is parsing the input file in a meaningful way (possibly into objects). I am having issues with the fact the input is of variable length, making looping very difficult.

Can anyone push me in the right direction? I'm not just being lazy looking for the answer. I just need a nudge. I'm stuck on this for half a day now.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to parse each line, it looks like you can safely match each line uniquely.

```
12345678 1234 1234 = ^(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)$ 
500 100            = ^(\d+)\s(\d+)$
B                  = ^B$ 
W 100              = ^W\s(\d+)
```

Since the first line is know, just convert it to an Integer manually.

Then walk the file, line by line, on each empty line start trying to parse the next lines with each of the regular expressions until you have a match. Use the regular expression groups `()` to extract the relevant data. Handle them accordingly. When you get an empty line, reset everything and start parsing with the regular expressions again.

Read up on Event Driven applications, which is what this is, the apparently `loop` in reading the file is a red-herring.

The blank lines represent the starts of logical set of events. Each line then represents an atomic event, which should easily map to a function/method call.

Comment: Thanks a million for you quick response. I used a variation of your suggestion and it worked. I used a switch statement based on line counter. Line 0: a/c num; pin; pin. Line

Comment: Line 1: Balance; overdraft. Default: A transactions. If first char is W, withdraw. B, balance. Else, end of transaction.

Comment: Hi, could you resolve the problem which you were facing? if possible could you provide your sample code for this problem...I am trying a similar one...